# For loop not working in C++

Tags: c++, for-loop

Well, here is my code and I am having a problem because my n is not increasing:

```
#define N               100 
#define N_EQUATIONS     18 + 2 

//initial values 
int v = 1;
int cai = 2;
int caSR = 3;
int nai = 4;
int ki = 5;
int dvdt = 18;

double V_init = -87.5;
double Cai_init=1.0e-4;
double cansr=1.2;
double cajsr=cansr;
double CaSR_init = cansr + cajsr;
double Nai_init = 7;
double Ki_init = 145;
double u[N + 1][N_EQUATIONS + 1];
double Im[N + 1];


int main () {

    int n = 0;

    for ( n = 0; n <= N; n++) {
        printf("n=%.18f\n", n);

        u[n][v] = V_init;
        //printf("t=%.18f\n", u[n][v]);
        u[n][cai] = Cai_init;
        //printf("cai=%.18f\n", u[n][cai]);
        u[n][caSR] = CaSR_init;
        u[n][nai] = Nai_init;
        u[n][ki] = Ki_init;
        u[n][dvdt] = 0.0;//check it
        tapend[n] = 0.0;
        tapstart[n] = 0.0;
    }
}
```

Sorry if it is a stupid question and the answer is staring me at the eyes..

P.S. see the new revised code

Comment: Learn to use a debugger. It will make your life much easier.

Comment: Your program shouldn't even compile! What is `cai` and `ki`? They are never declared anywhere. Same for many other variables.

Comment: I just added what cai and the other variables are stated. The problem is when I try to printf "N" it shows me N = 0, as if it doesn't read that definition at the top. So I tried to declare it inside the main loop as int but still I get the same problem..

Comment: Paul R has found your problem, you should take a look at [printf format specifiers](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/c/fprintf)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are probably just confused because your `printf` is incorrect:

```
printf("n=%.18f\n", n);
```

should be, e.g.

```
printf("n=%18d\n", n);
```

Currently you just print garbage in your loop (0 in your case, it seems, but it could be anything), so this may give the incorrect impression that `n` is not incrementing correctly.

**Note that if you enable compiler warnings (and compiler warnings should *always* be enabled), then the compiler would have pointed out this mistake to you. Always enable compiler warnings and always take notice of any warnings, understand them, and fix them.**